# How to conditionally change ascendancy?

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by

I want conditionally `orderBy` my query. All completed tasks (completed 1) should be below uncompleted and ordered by completion time and uncompleted task should be ordered by priority value. I am getting this with following statement:

```
orderBy = TaskTable.COLUMN_TASK_COMPLETED + " ASC, CASE " +TaskTable.COLUMN_TASK_COMPLETED+" WHEN 0 THEN " +TaskTable.COLUMN_TASK_PRIORITY +"  WHEN 1 THEN "+TaskTable.COLUMN_TASK_COMPLETED_TIME + "  END DESC";
```

Now, I want to change it, such way that priority is ordered with `ASC` attribute and `completed_time` is ordered with `DESC` attribute.

I tried:

```
orderBy = TaskTable.COLUMN_TASK_COMPLETED + " ASC, CASE " +TaskTable.COLUMN_TASK_COMPLETED+" WHEN 0 THEN " +TaskTable.COLUMN_TASK_PRIORITY +" ASK  WHEN 1 THEN "+TaskTable.COLUMN_TASK_COMPLETED_TIME + " DESC  END";
```

But it returns error:

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ASC": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM task_table WHERE (task_name LIKE ? ) ORDER BY task_completed ASC, CASE task_completed WHEN 0 THEN task_priority ASC  WHEN 1 THEN task_completed_time DESC  END

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASC/DESC specifications can be applied only to the top-level expressions used in the ORDER BY clause.

When you have a numeric column, you can simply negate its values, i.e., sort not by `X` but by `-X`.